# How to add project's name under "include" in installed location using CMake

Tags: cmake, pytorch

I'm building PyTorch (which uses CMake) and it installs its header files and folders directly inside the `include` directory. I'd like it to install the headers in a subdirectory of the `include` directory, named `pytorch` (or for my needs, `libtorch`).

Actual:

```
+- include
   +- torch
      +- library.h
      +- ...
```

Desired:

```
+- include
   +- pytorch
      +- torch
         +- library.h
         +- ...
```

Most other libraries I've built do this which is nice because it keeps the files organized.

How can I accomplish this with CMake?

Comment: `install(TARGETS library PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/pytorch/library.h)` instead of just `install(TARGETS library PUBLIC_HEADER)`???

Comment: @davidfong - I configure CMake with the "Unix Makefiles" generator, and I specify the destination with "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=".  I call CMake as usual from the "build" directory, and then I run "make" and "make install" to build & install respectively.  I'm open to any solutions, even if it means changing my approach.  I know I can do this with a script run post-install.  I assumed this would be a relatively small change to the PyTorch CMakeLists.txt, but maybe not?

Comment: Would a project use module [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) and its variables for install directories, then you could set variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR` to the desired directory with the header files. But it seems pytorch doesn't use that module and uses predefined directories for all its components (libraries, headers, modules). So you cannot change the directory where it installs headers.